# i want to receive a list from the user and make some steps in it and print it back after steps but its not working the way i want

Tags: python, string, list, input, split

```
def format_list(my_list):

  new_list =str(my_list[0:-1:2]) + ' and ' +str(my_list[-1])

  print(new_list)

  list_recived=input('Enter elements of a list separated by space ').split()

  format_list(list_recived)
```

**the input:** hydrogen helium lithium beryllium boron magnesium

**the output** ['hydrogen', 'lithium', 'boron'] and magnesium

**What I want that will be the output** hydrogen lithium boron and magnesium

Comment: You might want to add a python tag to this (looks like python to me) to get more visibility to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
str(my_list)
```

returns the representation of the list not each individual item
you can join the individual strings to one like so

```py
elements = ['hydrogen', 'lithium', 'boron'] 
print(" ".join(elements))
> 'hydrogen lithium boron'
```